# PHP number formatting back

Tags: php, numbers, format

I can formating number 169480 to 169,480.
But I can't 169,480 to simple 169480.
How can I do this?

I don't need any decimals and comma just a simple number.

Comment: `str_replace([',', '.'], '', $number);` remove commas and dots

Comment: @Gabor FYI: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(I just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace `'`, `.` and `,` with a empty string)

```
<?php

    $number = "169,480";
    echo str_replace(array("'", ".", ","), "", $number);

?>
```

Output:

```
169480
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
If number have any "," or "." means following code use for remove that

<?php
$number="169,480";
 echo str_replace([',', '.'], '', $number);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).